# ubuntu 22.04 LTS can not install Motherboard: AB350M PRO4-F, A320M PRO4-F

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have received equipment, at my educational center, with the following characteristics:

**AMD RYZEN 5 2600 Six-Core Processor x64
16 GB RAM
Graphics:
22P1W
1023MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 710
Motherboard: AB350M PRO4-F, A320M PRO4-F
OOSS: Windows 10 Pro Education 64/bit and EducandOS
**

I inserted a USB with **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** image, it is created with Balena Etcher.

The installation wizard takes a long time to start and a graphic error appears (this equipment has an additional graphics card and it does not use the one that comes with the motherboard)

Can someone help me with a suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The title of your question is quite misleading. Did you verify the USB? Rufus is a much better program for making the bootable USB, many report issue with the app you have used.

Comment: I used Balena Etcher. But it worked in other computers with other hardware

Comment: Yes you already said that but I standby my comment. Re download the ISO and re make the USB.

Comment: Have you checked for firmware updates for your MB?  Always hashcheck the downloaded ISO, and if possible, do a media check after burning the install media.